# SSRS Display Totals by Group

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to display the total for records that are grouped together.
I am using the code below under `Report Properties -> Code`

```
Dim public totalBalance as Integer 
Dim public Cnt as Integer 
Public Function AddTotal(ByVal balance AS Integer ) AS Integer 
                totalBalance = totalBalance + balance 
Cnt=Cnt+1 
                return balance 

End Function 

Public Function GetTotal() 
                return totalBalance
End Function


[Expression A is =Code.AddTotal(sum(DateDiff(dateinterval.Second, Lookup(Fields!dg_InteractionId.Value, Fields!Id.Value, Fields!StartDate.Value, "DataSet1"), Lookup(Fields!dg_InteractionId.Value, Fields!Id.Value, Fields!EndDate.Value, "DataSet1")))/CountRows())

While Expression B is =Code.GetTotal()
```

AS you can see the total 1651 for the top group is correct but the total for the second group 2597 is incorrect as it includes the total of the first group together. The correct result desired is 946 for the second group total.

Kindly advise.

[image: screenshot of table rows]

[image: screenshot of table numbers]

Comment: Why are you using code to calculate totals, and not using an expression in the total field.  All you need to do is type =SUM(field_you_want_to_sum.value)

Comment: the field is not in my table, it is a sum that is calculated from the difference in time of two date fields. then i need the total of the sum again in group.

Comment: In your code, before you return totalBalance, create a new variable that equals totalBalance.  Then set totalBlance = 0 and return the new variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your GetTotal() to reset the totalBalance variable when is called to display the group total

```
Public Function GetTotal() 
Dim bal AS integer
   bal = totalBalance
   totalBalance = 0
   return bal
End Function
```

Because of this change, you should also create a separate variable for the grand total which will be updated in the `AddTotal()` function, and create a `GetGrandTotal()` function which will return its value.

Also since you have declared your variables as public you can display them directly without functions like `=Code.totalBalance`